# Silverlight mime-type(s)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have stumbled across the following issue:

Using IIS6, I was trying to run sample Silverlight app. However, I experienced some problems with the mime-types. More specifically, I failed miserably when tried to use the **application/x-silverlight-2** type for my Object tag. No content was displayed at all. When I changed the type to **application/x-silverlight-app** everything seemed to work as expected. What is the difference between these two MIME types? As far as I know, application/x-silverlight-2 is supported by all versions of Sliverlight and there should be no problems to use it even with Siverlight 3 app. In contrast, I was no able to find concrete information what does the application/x-silverlight-app type stand for. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should check if the correct mime-type are configured in IIS6.
You can learn how to configure IIS6 for silverlight [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/).